# Cassandra datastax driver connections getting terminated abruptly

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.7.1 with  Cassandra 2.1.11. Following exception is thrown and it seems to be pointing to a protocol version issue, yet throwing a NPE instead of ProtocolException.

```
2016-01-26 17:46:29.426 TRACE - [launch worker-1] [74120143-3dc5-466d-8a71-68edbe03620d] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection      : Connection[/192.172.2.51:9042-1, inFlight=1, closed=false] writing request
 PREPARE SELECT * FROM loops WHERE venue_id = ? AND loop_state = ?  AND covers_year = ?  AND covers_month = ?  AND covers_day = 0 
2016-01-26 17:46:29.427 DEBUG - [r2-nio-worker-1] [74120143-3dc5-466d-8a71-68edbe03620d] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection      : Connection[/192.172.1.51:9042-3, inFlight=0, closed=false] connection error
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolOptions.getProtocolVersionEnum(ProtocolOptions.java:178)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.protocolVersion(QueryLogger.java:753)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.parameterValueAsString(QueryLogger.java:738)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.appendParameters(QueryLogger.java:709)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.logQuery(QueryLogger.java:647)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.maybeLogNormalQuery(QueryLogger.java:631)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger$ConstantThresholdQueryLogger.maybeLogNormalOrSlowQuery(QueryLogger.java:278)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(QueryLogger.java:620)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.reportLatency(Cluster.java:1422)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:607)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:991)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:913)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.epollInReady(EpollSocketChannel.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:326)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-01-26 17:46:29.427 TRACE - [r2-nio-worker-4] [74120143-3dc5-466d-8a71-68edbe03620d] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection      : Connection[/192.172.2.51:9042-1, inFlight=1, closed=false] request sent successfully
2016-01-26 17:46:29.430 DEBUG - [r2-nio-worker-1] [74120143-3dc5-466d-8a71-68edbe03620d] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection      : Defuncting connection to /192.172.1.51:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.172.1.51:9042] Unexpected exception triggered (java.lang.NullPointerException)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:1028)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:271)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.epollInReady(EpollSocketChannel.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:326)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolOptions.getProtocolVersionEnum(ProtocolOptions.java:178)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.protocolVersion(QueryLogger.java:753)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.parameterValueAsString(QueryLogger.java:738)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.appendParameters(QueryLogger.java:709)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.logQuery(QueryLogger.java:647)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.maybeLogNormalQuery(QueryLogger.java:631)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger$ConstantThresholdQueryLogger.maybeLogNormalOrSlowQuery(QueryLogger.java:278)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(QueryLogger.java:620)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.reportLatency(Cluster.java:1422)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:607)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:991)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:913)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        ... 16 more
2016-01-26 17:46:29.431 TRACE - [r2-nio-worker-4] [74120143-3dc5-466d-8a71-68edbe03620d] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection      : Connection[/192.172.2.51:9042-1, inFlight=1, closed=false] received: RESULT PREPARED 0xc66a551ecfc5ac34839e19fdfa0c5705 [venue_id (uuid)][loop_state (varchar)][covers_year (int)][covers_month (int)] (resultMetadata=[venue_id (uuid)][loop_state (varchar)][covers_year (int)][covers_month (int)][covers_day (int)][start (timestamp)][created_on (timestamp)][end (timestamp)][id (uuid)][iterations (int)][playlist (list<frozen<ums_qa."LoopMediaAsset">>)][slots (list<frozen<ums_qa."Slot">>)][updated_on (timestamp)])
```

Both Cassandra nodes are working fine and accepting connections. Some how the driver seems to be closing the connections arbitrarily. Was unable to find a similar issue reported anywhere. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the driver is not initialized yet, but then there shouldn't be an open connection trying to execute a PREPARE. Could you share how you initialize the `Cluster` and `Session` objects? Do you prepare that statement yourself from your code? Did you do anything special with ProtocolOptions (wrap it or subclass it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are connecting to Cassandra from the nodes of a spark cluster and using a helper class which initializes the Cassandra `Cluster` and `Session`.

The issue turns out to be in this initialization as @OlivierMichallat pointed out. It seems multiple clusters were getting created, probably because the helper class was loaded multiple times from spark workers.This goes against one of the rules suggested by DataStax, which is to [use one `Cluster` instance per physical cluster](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra). Synchronizing this initialization solved the issue for us. Thanks for the directions guys.

Answer (score 2):

There was a minor native protocol version increase between 2.1.8 and 2.1.9 - by using the 2.1.7 driver with a 2.1.11 server, you have a native-proto version number offered by the server that's not recognized by the client.

Given the stack trace (and the code in the driver at those lines - https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/f4240267b3a3b829fa51242441dd219424a91347/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ProtocolOptions.java#L168-L179 ), I'd probably start by upgrading to the latest 2.1.11+ cassandra-driver version to rule that out.